# inequality and normalization

Tags: inequality

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ three reals such that $a>b>c$, $a>0$, $c<0$ and $a+b+c=0$. I want to prove that 
$$\frac{\sqrt{6}|b|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}<1$$
I suppose here that $a^2+b^2+c^2\neq 0$.

I'm facing this inequality when trying to normalize the value of $b$ in a problem of computational fluid dynamics.

Answer (score 1):

If $b \ge 0$ then
$$ 
 a > b \ge 0 \Longrightarrow  a^2 >  b^2 \\
 c = -a - b <  -2b  \le 0 \Longrightarrow  c^2 > 4 b^2
$$
If $b \le 0 $ then 
$$
 c < b \le 0 \Longrightarrow  c^2 > b^2 \\
 a = -b - c > -2b \ge  0 \Longrightarrow  a^2 > 4 b^2
$$
Therefore in  any case
$$
a^2 + b^2 + c^2 > 6 b^2
$$
which implies the desired inequality.

Comment: @mechja: You are welcome! – You might consider to *accept* the answer (if it helped), by clicking on the check mark.